# Filtering by an untranslatable method using EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

In a web application with a SQL Server database, I have implemented the data access layer using the "Repository Pattern". For filtering a `User` based on its email, I'm using an expression like this:

```
var emailFilter = "user@example.com";
var query = _dbContext.Set<User>().Where(x => x.Email.Normalize() == emailFilter.Normalize());
var result = query.ToListAsync();
```

But EF Core throws an exception which says:

> ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

I have more than 200k users in the users' table and I don't want to filter data on the client-side.

**The mentioned code is only an example but I mean other use cases with more complex methods.**

Now, how can I use complex functions to filter data on the server-side?

Comment: Only if you can rewrite them into an expression. But why should *stored* email addresses be "normalized" before filtering? Shouldn't they rather be normalized before saving?

Comment: @GertArnold It's only a sample, I mean what to do with untranslatable functions? Should I implement these methods using T-SQL?

Comment: Either that (and map it to a [`DbFunction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionattribute?view=efcore-3.1) in the context) or rewrite it as an expression. But in general, you should always avoid using functions before filtering. It won't perform.

Comment: If there was a "generic", mechanical way of transforming untranslatable methods so that they can work, why would the EF team not have implemented that transformation inside EF?

Comment: Generic "server side filtering with untranslatable method" makes no sense. You either make it translatable, or it won't run server side.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you, first normalize your email in db by bulk update :

by [Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore/)

```
_dbContext.Set<User>().update(x => new User {Email =  x.Email.Normalize()}  ;
```

then

```
emailFilter = ("user@example.com").Normalize();
var query = _dbContext.Set<User>().Where(x => x.Email  == emailFilter);
var result = query.ToListAsync();
```

> it's an instance solution

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I mean a generic solution for any other untranslatable methods. I have updated the question

Comment: Ef convert c# to sql some complex function can not translate. you must be simplize your code.

Answer (score 0):

For non standard go with plain sql queries...

```
var emailFilter = "user@example.com";
var result = await _dbContext.Users.FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM dbo.Users WHERE LOWER(Email) = {emailFilter}").ToListAsync();
```

Or use Functions

```
var emailFilter = "user@example.com";
var result = await _dbContext.Users.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.Email, $"%{emailFilter}%")).ToListAsync();
```

With the penalty of the performance...